# Run a Jenkins pipeline build when a subdirectory changes

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins pipeline involving two repos. Let's call them "client" and "server". This pipeline builds the server binary in the first stage, then runs integration tests in the client repo in the second stage.

This build should run when certain directories change in either project (e.g. `client.git/foo`, `server.git/bar`, `server.git/baz`). How do I do this? The options under "Build triggers" all seem to assume a single repository.

Comment: did you find any solution or workaround to this ?